# Kivy: how to display a widget while waiting for another one to be displayed (both called from a same event)

Tags: python, widget, kivy

When an "OK button" is clicking, my kivy app retrieves a list of sometimes 100+ folders and displays a GridLayout with 4 columns and 1 row per folder. Each row has 3 scrollable labels and 1 checkbox. This GridLayout sometimes takes close to 12 sec to be generated so I would like to display something (a label, an image...) in the meantime.

**Attempt 1:** My "Ok button" calls a def DisplayTable. I tried to simply add `self.add_widget(Label_when_waiting)` right at the beginning of DisplayTable (so before any processing or generating the GridLayout) but the `Label_when_waiting` is displayed only when GridLayout is displayed.

**Attempt 2:** I tried to separate def DisplayTable into two def, `Diplay_Label_when_waiting`(the one called by the "OK button")  and `DisplayTable`:

```
def Diplay_Label_when_waiting(self, *args):
    self.add_widget(Label_when_waiting)
    DisplayTable(self, *args)
```

But here again, `Label_when_waiting` is displayed only when GridLayout is displayed.

So how can I display Label_when_waiting before GridLayout knowing that both displays have to be triggered by the "Ok button"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **Clock.schedule_once** to display the Grid after the label is shown:

```
def Diplay_Label_when_waiting(self, *args):
    self.add_widget(Label_when_waiting)
    Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: DisplayTable(self, *args), 0)
```

You can also use **delayable** from *kivyoav* (DISCLAIMER - I'm the author ...)

```
from kivyoav.delayed import delayable

@delayable
def Diplay_Label_when_waiting(self, *args):
    self.add_widget(Label_when_waiting)
    yield 0.0 # delay of 0ms , will cause the UI to update...
    DisplayTable(self, *args)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is working. Thanks for the module, I will try it tomorrow  I don’t understand why it works with a clock and not when I call the definition directly. Why should I use a clock?

Comment: To let the kivy event loop time to update the screen

Comment: Thanks Yoav for your answer. I am still confused, if it's only to give time to update the screen, why  `time.sleep`  isn't working (this code doesn't display the label: `self.add_widget(Label_when_waiting)    time.sleep(5)    self.DisplayTable(self)` )

Comment: Because the **main event loop thread** is stuck on the **sleep call** - In other words the event loop is waiting for your function to end, It doesn't matter if you *sleep* or do *real work*, if the function doesn't return the event loop is stuck.